# C++ templates: late instantiation of enable_if member function warning

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I'm trying to late instantiate an enabled_if class member function (need it to bypass circular dependencies), but I'm getting "**warning C4544: 'itemType_inner': default template argument ignored on this template declaration**" in Visual Studio 2017 (/std:c++latest).
Now I've read what it says at [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4544](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4544), but I didn't understand it and the example doesn't help me either.

Now if I have a normal class, I late instantiate the template as:

```
template <typename itemType> class A
{
    public: bool Function_1( int variable ) const;
};

template <typename itemType> bool A<itemType>::Function_1( int variable ) const
{
    return false;
}
```

But if I try the same technique with the enable_if function, I get the warning:

```
template <typename itemType> class A
{
public: 
    template<class itemType_inner = itemType> 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<itemType_inner>::value, bool >::type Function_2( int variable ) const;
};

template <typename itemType> 
template<class itemType_inner = itemType> 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<itemType_inner>::value, bool >::type A<itemType>::Function_2( int variable ) const
{
    return false;
}
```

Now any clarification on what C4544 really means in my case and how to remove it would be really appreciated.

Br
Waldemar

Comment: Just remove `= itemType` from the definition. The one from the declaration is enough.

Comment: What does the warning mean in the first place?